# Reducing the width of truncation in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` (cell) with some `textlabel` in it. The string in the text label could be of any length. I wanted to have ellipsis when the text exceeds a certain length. So, I added the below code,

```
cell.textlabel.adjustsFontSizeToWidth = NO;
cell.textlabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

This code truncates the label to fit to the screen size. I need to reduce the truncation even further. Is there any possibility of reducing the width of the truncation in the text label ?

We don't want to modify the actually text as we will be using it for computation purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not ? , cell.textlabel.adjustsFontSizeToWidth = YES;

Comment: @sheshnath I think OP is asking for reducing truncation of the text with ellipsis. I suppose he doesn't want the text to fit to the width of the screen.